# Display table data if

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im not sure if you'll get what I'm asking, but I'll try to be as specific and clear as possible.
I have this PHP code :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM batai WHERE svarbumas=1 ORDER BY id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    extract($row);
    $link=$row["linkas"];
    echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($link);

    if($width > $height) {
        echo "<img src="$link" style='height:234px;margin-left:-33%'>";
    }
    else if($width < $height) {
        echo "<img src="$link" style='width:234px;margin-top:-33%>";
    }

    echo "</div>";
}
```

what I want it to do, is to center a given image from a database into a div, for example, if the given images width is bigger than height, it echos it with a left margin.
But the problem is, that the page only displays two of the elements. one, where height is bigger than width and one, where width is bigger than height.

if I don't type any ifs and just echo the image, every image from the database gets display. I really hope you understand my question and am thankful for your advice :)

Comment: Your variable is sometimes called `$link` and sometimes `$linkas`, is it only in the question (copy/paste mistake) or is it the same in your code?

Comment: thats only  the question, it's fine in the code

Comment: As I understand, you can use image resize libraries to display the images same width and height even original image is in different height and width. By using css we can make it center align both horizontally and vertically also.

Comment: @sponkau First try and see whether you get proper height and width of image, because this is your first checkpoint, echo it out for better try. Will move to the next point after.

Comment: @divy3993 I do get proper height and width. and the ifs work fine, images get centered just as I like, the problem is, they are centered only once. then nothing else is displayed. It seems that the while breaks for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your double quotes, or use single quotes and concatenate.

```
if($width > $height) {
        echo "<img src=\"$link\" style='height:234px;margin-left:-33%'>";
    }
    else if($width < $height) {
        echo "<img src=\"$link\" style='width:234px;margin-top:-33%'>";
    }
```

or

```
   if($width > $height) {
            echo '<img src="' . $link . '" style="height:234px;margin-left:-33%">';
        }
        else if($width < $height) {
            echo '<img src="' . $link . '" style="width:234px;margin-top:-33%">';
        }
```

Error reporting would have given you a message such as

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';'' in

So in the future you should turn on error reporting, http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.

Comment: Please see note about error reporting as well. It will be useful for you for debugging these issues in the future.